# normalized mean curvature flow with convex initial hypersurface has finite velocity

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, mean-curvature-flows

I can't understand the prove in [Xi-Ping Zhu] Lectures on mean curvature flows. The statement as follow.

---

**Lemma 3.5** (page 32)

There exists a positive constant $C$ such that
$$\textrm{sup}\{\overline{H}(x,\tau)|x\in M^n, r\geq 0 \}\leq C.$$

---

I can follow all the step but the last one. I don't know why

$$0\leq \frac{1}{S- \rho_0 }[2H^2-\rho_0|A|^2H]$$

at $(z_1,t_1)$ implies

$$H(z,t)\leq Cr_{out}(t_0)^{-1} ,$$ for all $z\in S^n, t\in[0,t_0].$

Here, $\Psi=\frac{H}{S-\rho_0}$ and $\Psi$ has its maximum at $(z_1,t_1)$

---

I tried like this.
$$H(z,t)\leq \Phi(z,t)(S(z,t)-\rho_0)\leq\Psi(z_1,t_1)(S(z,t)-\rho_0)\leq\frac{S(z,t)-\rho_0}{S(z_1,t_1)-\rho_0}H(z_1,t_1).$$
From $0\leq \frac{1}{S- \rho_0 }[2H^2-\rho_0|A|^2H]$, I obtain $H\leq \frac{2n}{\rho_0}$ by Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. Thus,
$$H(z,t)\leq\frac{S(z,t)}{2\rho_0-\rho_0}\frac{2n}{\rho_0}=\frac{2nS}{\rho_0^2}$$

Is this approach right? If so, how to continue? If not, how to explain?

Please, help me..

Thank you!